# Appcelerator Module will not link

Tags: ios, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to upgrade an old `iOS` appcelerator module that requires the AssetsLibrary.

I've upgraded the module with the latest version of XCode and have successfully installed it into Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.5.0.201602170821.

When I try and run from studio, my Appcelerator `XCode` project will not link because it's missing the `AssetsLibrary`. I've confirmed this by manually adding the `AssetsLibrary` library in `XCode`.

The manually added reference to `AssetsLibrary` disappears the next time I try and run from studio.

It appears that my module.xconfig is trying to reference the AssetsLibrary.  Here's the contents of my module.xconfig found in my build/iphone directory:

> // this is a generated file - DO NOT EDIT

```
FACEBOOK_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=$(SRCROOT)/../../modules/iphone/facebook/5.0.1/platform "~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/facebook/5.0.1/platform"
FACEBOOK_OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework Social -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework FBSDKShareKit
MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphoneos4__=$(inherited) -framework AssetsLibrary
MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphonesimulator4__=$(inherited) -framework AssetsLibrary
MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphoneos5__=$(inherited) -framework AssetsLibrary
MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphonesimulator5__=$(inherited) -framework AssetsLibrary
MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphoneos6__=$(inherited) -framework AssetsLibrary
MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphonesimulator6__=$(inherited) -framework AssetsLibrary
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS=$(inherited) $(FACEBOOK_FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS) 
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) $(FACEBOOK_OTHER_LDFLAGS) 
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos4*]=$(inherited) $(MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphoneos4__) 
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator4*]=$(inherited) $(MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphonesimulator4__) 
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos5*]=$(inherited) $(MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphoneos5__) 
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator5*]=$(inherited) $(MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphonesimulator5__) 
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphoneos6*]=$(inherited) $(MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphoneos6__) 
OTHER_LDFLAGS[sdk=iphonesimulator6*]=$(inherited) $(MY_MEDIA_OTHER_LDFLAGS_sdk_iphonesimulator6__)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what going wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for editing that comment block, I tried to add the file as comment block but could only get part of it to show correctly.  Is there a way to apply a comment block to selected text when posting?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what fixed the problem for me.

Step 1:

Find the module.xcconfig file in the folder that appcelerator installed the module into.  For me it was at

/Users/MyUserName/library/application support/Titanium/modules/iphone/my.media/0.2

Step 2:

Add the following line to the top of the module.xcconfig file

OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework AssetsLibrary

These 2 steps fixed it for me.